# Can run script line by line in shell, but full script returns nothing

Tags: python, shell

I'm using a script that extracts text from a PDF file. If I run my script one line at a time in the shell, it works fine (i.e. the extracted text is returned in the shell window), but if I try and execute the entire script, nothing gets returned. The script is as follows:

```
import PyPDF2

pdfFileObj = open('c:\Python27\meetingminutes.pdf', 'rb')    
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)    
pdfReader.numPages    
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)    
pageObj.extractText()
```

I'm very new to Python, so all help is appreciated!

Comment: `print(pageObj.extractText())`

Comment: "*I'm very new to Python*" - In that case, may I suggest that you stop what you are doing and read [the Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)? It will answer this and many other questions even before you ask them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Python shell *echoes* the results of expressions. In a script, you need to explicitly *print* your results:

```
print pageObj.extractText()
```

If Python where to behave differently, you could never write a script that remained silent.

Technically speaking, what the Python interactive shell does is use the [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr), so every expression (unless it produces `None`) is written using `print repr(<expression outcome>)`. `print` without `repr()` would use the [`str()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) instead.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony: typo / thinko. The interactive interpreter is also called a REPL, a *Read, Evaluate, Print Loop*, which is probably why I slipped up.