# Side Effect error in Python in an online compiler

Tags: python

I am getting Side effects error in Python while compiling it in an online compiler

Tried to change some syntax, but the error persists

```
def rotate(A): 
 N = len(A[0]) 
 for i in range(N // 2): 
  for j in range(i, N - i - 1): 
   temp = A[i][j] 
   A[i][j] = A[N - 1 - j][i] 
   A[N - 1 - j][i] = A[N - 1 - i][N - 1 - j] 
   A[N - 1 - i][N - 1 - j] = A[j][N - 1 - i] 
   A[j][N - 1 - i] = temp  
 return A
```

rotate([[1,2],[3,4]])

Expected Output 
[[3, 1], [4, 2]]\n

Actual Output is 
Side effect\n

if I change the final command from return to print(A), the output - [[3, 1], [4, 2]]\n Sid...   which means something is extending my output which is to be terminated.

[Showing Side Effect Error in some Python Complilers for matrixflip function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54774723/showing-side-effect-error-in-some-python-complilers-for-matrixflip-function)

this person is getting the same type of error

```
def rotate(A): 
 N = len(A[0]) 
 for i in range(N // 2): 
  for j in range(i, N - i - 1): 
   temp = A[i][j] 
   A[i][j] = A[N - 1 - j][i] 
   A[N - 1 - j][i] = A[N - 1 - i][N - 1 - j] 
   A[N - 1 - i][N - 1 - j] = A[j][N - 1 - i] 
   A[j][N - 1 - i] = temp 
   print(A)
 return none
```

After editing a bit I passed one of test cases, but getting a runtime error in 2 of the 3 error cases
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6GqQ.jpg

Guys, it finally worked !!!!!

```
def rotate(A):   
 N = len(A[0]) 
 for i in range(N // 2): 
  for j in range(i, N - i - 1): 
   temp = A[i][j] 
   A[i][j] = A[N - 1 - j][i] 
   A[N - 1 - j][i] = A[N - 1 - i][N - 1 - j] 
   A[N - 1 - i][N - 1 - j] = A[j][N - 1 - i] 
   A[j][N - 1 - i] = temp    
 print(A)
 return none
```

Thanks everyone for the much required help for a new comer here

Comment: Are you getting an actual python error? If so, please provide the full error traceback. If it's a site error, that will be dependent on the site error.

Comment: I am getting the perfect output on actual python, the online compiler is giving me this error.

Comment: Which online interpreter? Tried it here: https://repl.it/languages/python3 and works just as expected....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can run script line by line in shell, but full script returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891521/can-run-script-line-by-line-in-shell-but-full-script-returns-nothing)

Comment: a mooc course https://nptel.ac.in/

Comment: I am not importing any file, so I guess that error is different

Comment: This is likely a question to take up with the site owner

Comment: I was guessing if any syntax manipulations could solve the error, if not, that might be the only way

Comment: Since this is for a course.. did the question specify that your function must have no side effects? You are mutating the input object, which is a side effect.

Comment: It is showing "Wrong Answer" following the Side effect error. Any tips how to mutate the input without the side effect error?

Comment: Yes -- see my answer.  Remove the `return A` line entirely; the function will return naturally upon falling off the bottom, and will return `None`.  The mutation is still valid, but is then the *purpose* of the function, rather than a side effect.

Comment: @Prune it is still a side-effect.

Comment: after removing return A, I passed one of the test cases, but a new runtime error occured

Comment: Okay -- post a new question, then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have confused the compiler as to your purpose in writing this function.  Most functions *either* return a result *or* alter the input parameters.  You do both: return a result, and have "unexpected" side effects on the input.  This is generally poor function design, and this compiler considers it an error.

Do one of two things to fix this:

1. Make a local copy of `A` to manipulate and return.
2. Simply return from the function when you're done; do not return an extra copy of `A`.

Comment: Note: If this is some sort of coding challenge site, there is a strong possibility that only one of the two options will be accepted (because the exercise has a specific constraint on behavior to match one or the other of the behaviors). If the error is "Side effect" (implying the argument should not be changed), option #1 may be the only one it will accept.

Comment: Also, a note: You probably want to use `copy.deepcopy` to perform the copy here (since this is a 2D `list` of `list`s, so simple shallow copies a la `A = A[:]` won't be enough; `A = [row[:] for row in A]` would probably do the job, but manually implementing `deepcopy` is always risky, so use `copy.deepcopy` when a shallow copy isn't sufficient).